# Best way to reorganize array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I need reorganize and array of linked objects by id to only one tree object. The depth level is unknown, so that I think that it should be done recursively. What is the most efficient way?

I have the next array of objects:

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4
  }
]
```

I want restructure for have a only one object like a tree:

```js
const treeObj = {
  "id": 1,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "id": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each object has other many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive mapping function over all the `children`.

```js
const arrObj = [ { "id": 1, "children": [ { "id": 2 }, { "id": 3 } ] }, { "id": 2, "children": [ { "id": 4 }, { "id": 5 } ] }, { "id": 3, "children": [ { "id": 6 } ] }, { "id": 4 } ];
const res = arrObj[0];//assuming the first element is the root
res.children = res.children.map(function getChildren(obj){
  const child = arrObj.find(x => x.id === obj.id);
  if(child?.children) child.children = child.children.map(getChildren);
  return child || obj;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: yes, it's my firs solution, but i don't sure that it be most efficient

Comment: This solution runs in linear time compared to the number of nodes. There isn't really any way to lower the time complexity because it is always necessary to iterate over all the nodes.